# Not working scp command: Connection closed by remote host (Mac OS X)

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, scp

I'm working on a remote server through Mac terminal, since I updated it to OSX 10.10 from 10.5 I started receiving this message every time I try to `scp` from the server to my computer:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
lost connection
```

If I perform `scp` backwards (copying from mac to server) it works just fine, and it works fine if I do it form another mac.

If I do a verobse `scp`, it gives me this:

```
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host xx.xx.xx.x, user User, command scp -v -t /Users/User
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.x [xx.xx.xx.x] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
lost connection
```

I tried looking in the various host, config, ssh files but I didn't mange to solve much.

Comment: Is the server configured for key-pair auth only?

Comment: I have to ask the admin, but i really think so

Comment: In that case I think the issue might be that you don't have the private key for your server user.

Comment: But i can connect to it and perform any other action, this is the only one that stopped working after the upgrade

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just had the same issues with an SCP from my personal Mac to a Mac desktop we use as a local server. Running `sudo sshd -t` showed me the following hint:

```
/var/empty must be owned by root and not group or world-writable
```

All I did was change the owner back to root (I'm not sure why it wasn't already, but I remember upgrading from Mavericks to Yosemite gave me a couple headaches regarding permissions):

```
cd /var
sudo chown root empty
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks man!! That command `sudo sshd -t` showed me the exact issue i was having! (a missing **#** in a line of the sshd_config file)
Problem Solved!!!

Comment: Thanks so much.  Same symptoms and this resolved my issue.  I was trying to SSH from 10.13 macOS to 10.11 OS X.

Answer (score 3):

I got this problem too.

I tried "sudo sshd -t" , but there seemed no problem.

Then I checked my "hosts.allow" & "hosts.deny", no problem ether.

Finally I found out that I use the **'~'** path int the command, here's it:

`scp ~/Downloads/afile root@host2:~/Downloads`

I changed it to the following one:

```
scp /home/Downloads/afile root@host2:/home/Downloads
```

**And it works now.** Hope this can help.

Answer (score 2):

Check the target user's `.bashrc` or equivalent file. `~/.bashrc` is sourced for non-interactive logins. If there's an `echo` or command that outputs anything, it will break the SCP protocol.

Comment: The remote server is dropping the TCP connection immediately after accepting it. The OP isn't successfully starting an ssh session, much less logging in. The contents of his remote home directory doesn't matter.

Comment: Excellent answer, I've been struggling with this for quite a while. Temporarily I had to rename my .bash_profile and .bashrc scripts so that they don't mess up with the scp transfer, after the scp transfer finished then I restored these bash files. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

'sudo sshd -t' clearly showed which config line is not valid. Got over the SCP problem once commenting that config line. Thanks a lot for answers.

Answer (score 1):

Add -O ( Letter )

scp -O { filename } {user}@{ip}:{path}

Example:
scp -O filename.txt root@192.168.x.x:/usr/home

Answer (score 0):

System Preferences pane → Sharing applet → check the Remote Login checkbox. This will enable SSH, and in turn, SCP.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error when I was using `scp -P [wrong_custom_port] user@host:/source /destination`

After googling for a while and not finding any direct answers I finally realized that I was using different custom port number for my ssh connection on remote host.

Hope this to help someone with similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

*i'll throw my hat in the ring* on this one.

i got bit  by this issue today trying to scp a file from one computer on my LAN to my macbook, and got presented with the lovely message to STDOUT

```
scp: Connection closed
```

that didn't really give me much to work with and adding `-VVVV` didn't show any glaring issues, though using `-VVVV` when stuff like this isn't working is not something that i look at everyday (may have missed something).

all that said, the above commands of `sudo sshd -t` printed **nothing** to STDOUT.

so where to go from here, fortunately i've experienced issues with ssh in the past, and IMHO the easiest way to get a *sane* message on why a certain ssh related task ie. *scping* a file to ssh server of some sort is to **stop** the currently running server and start it in **debug** mode from a terminal in a foreground process (it may be possible start another ssh server to prevent stopping the existing one if an ssh config file is set properly (not something i've looked into)), but for my use, stopping the existing server and launching a new instance of it in **debug** works wonders ‍♀️, so running

```
sshd -d
```

and then attempting to send a file to the server i see the following lines in STDOUT

```
debug1: server_input_channel_req: channel 0 request subsystem reply 1
debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req subsystem
debug1: subsystem: cannot stat /usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.8p1/libexec/sftp-server: No such file or directory
debug1: subsystem: exec() /usr/local/Cellar/openssh/8.8p1/libexec/sftp-server
Starting session: subsystem 'sftp' for capin from 10.0.1.42 port 63866 id 0
debug1: Received SIGCHLD.
debug1: session_by_pid: pid 2107
debug1: session_exit_message: session 0 channel 0 pid 2107
debug1: session_exit_message: release channel 0
Received disconnect from 10.0.1.42 port 63866:11: disconnected by user
Disconnected from user capin 10.0.1.42 port 63866
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: do_cleanup
debug1: PAM: cleanup
debug1: PAM: closing session
debug1: PAM: deleting credentials
```

which makes me think those error/warning messages are my issue, and to continue troubleshooting from there.

Comment: Perhaps related to https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/451281/unable-to-scp-since-upgrade-to-ventura

Answer (score -1):

User on server and on your desktop have to create keys locally before using ssh (or scp). You can create a strong key (algorithm RSA and length 4096) with this command :

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "username"
```

If you already have key on your server check permission on **~/.ssh** dir

As mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/215504/permissions-on-private-key-in-ssh-folder), owner of .ssh dir and file in this directory must be your user. Permission on **.ssh** dir must be **700 (drwx------)**, private key files **600 (-rw------)** and public key must be **644 (-rw-r--r--)**. You can check this with :

```
ls -alh
```

If it is not the case you can change this :

```
   chown -R username ~/.ssh
   chmod 700 ~/.ssh
   chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_*
   chmod 644 ~/.ssh/*.pub
```

Comment: The session is failing before any kind of key exchange is performed. The quality of the keys doesn't matter.

Comment: You can exchange key because you have not key. line "debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/XXXXXXXX type -1" means you have not key file for authentification on the client machine. Because you have not possibility to enter a password, identification by password seems disable on server

Comment: But it's weird bc i can perform any other action (connect, read, write, copy on server, etc..). This is the only one i'm forbid

Comment: Can you perfom all theses operations from your mac and to your mac ? Do you have an sshd on your mac ?

Comment: i use the ssh -X for connecting and yes, i can perform all of them except scp from server to mac